# Conditionally fill/color of voronoi segments

Tags: d3.js, voronoi

I'm trying to conditionally color these voronoi segments based on the 'd.lon' value. If it's positive, I want it to be green, if it's negative I want it to be red. However at the moment it's returning every segment as green.

Even if I swap my < operand to >, it still returns green.

Live example here: https://allaffects.com/world/

Thank you :)

**JS**

```
// Stating variables
var margin = {top: 20, right: 40, bottom: 30, left: 45},
width = parseInt(window.innerWidth) - margin.left - margin.right; 
height = (width * .5) - 10;

var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
.center([0, 5 ])
.scale(200)
.rotate([0,0]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height);

var path = d3.geo.path()
.projection(projection);

var voronoi = d3.geom.voronoi()
.x(function(d) { return d.x; })
.y(function(d) { return d.y; })
.clipExtent([[0, 0], [width, height]]);

var g = svg.append("g");

// Map data
d3.json("/world-110m2.json", function(error, topology) {

// Cities data
d3.csv("/cities.csv", function(error, data) {
g.selectAll("circle")
   .data(data)
   .enter()
   .append("a")
              .attr("xlink:href", function(d) {
                  return "https://www.google.com/search?q="+d.city;}
              )
   .append("circle")
   .attr("cx", function(d) {
           return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[0];
   })
   .attr("cy", function(d) {
           return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[1];
   })
   .attr("r", 5)
   .style("fill", "red");

});

g.selectAll("path")
  .data(topojson.object(topology, topology.objects.countries)
      .geometries)
.enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", path)
});

var voronoi = d3.geom.voronoi()
        .clipExtent([[0, 0], [width, height]]);

  d3.csv("/cities.csv", function(d) {
    return [projection([+d.lon, +d.lat])[0], projection([+d.lon, +d.lat]) [1]];
  }, function(error, rows) {
    vertices = rows;
      console.log(vertices);
      drawV(vertices);
    }
  );

      function polygon(d) {
          return "M" + d.join("L") + "Z";
      }

      function drawV(d) {
          svg.append("g")
            .selectAll("path")
            .data(voronoi(d), polygon)
           .enter().append("path")
            .attr("class", "test")
            .attr("d", polygon)

// This is the line I'm trying to get to conditionally fill the segment.
            .style("fill", function(d) { return (d.lon < 0 ? "red" : "green"     );} )
            .style('opacity', .7)
            .style('stroke', "pink")
            .style("stroke-width", 3);
      }
```

**JS EDIT**

```
d3.csv("/static/cities.csv", function(data) {
    var rows = [];
    data.forEach(function(d){
        //Added third item into my array to test against for color
        rows.push([projection([+d.lon, +d.lat])[0], projection([+d.lon, +d.lat]) [1], [+d.lon]])
    });

    console.log(rows); // data for polygons and lon value
    console.log(data); // data containing raw csv info (both successfully log)

    svg.append("g")
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(voronoi(rows), polygon)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", polygon)
  //Trying to access the third item in array for each polygon which contains the lon value to test
    .style("fill", function(data) { return (rows[2] < 0 ? "red" : "green" );} ) 
    .style('opacity', .7)
    .style('stroke', "pink")
    .style("stroke-width", 3)
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what's happening: your row function is modifying the objects of `rows` array. At the time you get to the function for filling the polygons there is no `d.lon` anymore, and since `d.lon` is `undefined` the ternary operator is evaluated to `false`, which gives you "green".

Check this:

```js
var d = {};

console.log(d.lon < 0 ? "red" : "green");
```

Which also explains what you said:

> Even if I swap my < operand to >, it still returns green.

Because `d.lon` is undefined, it doesn't matter what operator you use.

That being said, you have to keep your original `rows` structure, with the `lon` property in the objects.

A solution is getting rid of the row function...

```
d3.csv("cities.csv", function(data){
    //the rest of the code
})
```

... and creating your `rows` array inside the callback:

```
var rows = [];
data.forEach(function(d){
    rows.push([projection([+d.lon, +d.lat])[0], projection([+d.lon, +d.lat]) [1]])
});
```

Now you have two arrays: `rows`, which you can use to create the polygons just as you're using now, and `data`, which contains the `lon` values.

Alternatively, you can keep everything in just one array (just changing your row function), which is the best solution because it would make easier to get the `d.lon` values inside the enter selection for the polygons. However, it's hard providing a working answer without testing it with your actual code (it normally ends up with the OP saying *"it's not working!"*).

Comment: Thanks Gerado :) I've updated my example code and linked example with your suggestions. You'll see I can successfully log both the data and rows arrays. I'm trying to implement your second suggestion of keeping everything in one array, I'm not able to iterate though the rows data and access the .lon value in my conditional .style fill statement.

Comment: As I said, the only way to help you with the second suggestion is if you provide a working code (put that code in your link in a Plunker/Fiddle?CodePen/Whatever, so we can modify it). Regarding the first suggestion, you're doing it wrong. Try this: `.style("fill", function(d,i) { return data[i].lon < 0 ? "red" : "green";} )`.

Comment: Thank you very much :D That's exactly what I was trying to do. Marked as correct.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Hi, and thank you both for this post. I've got a very similar issue with a D3 V4 example directly inspired by this : bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7608400 . I tried to change one of the typeAirport function by adding a third parameter in the array (like you did with rows) but can't get the content of the array... Shoud I write a new question ? Thanks in advance, and have a nice day

Comment: @Raphadasilva yes, please post a new question.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado No problem, it's here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47236733/voronoi-cells-fill-function-with-d3-v4 :-)

Comment: @GerardoFurtado sorry to insist, but have you had a chance to see the new question ? Thanks in advance :-) ! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47236733/voronoi-cells-fill-function-with-d3-v4

Comment: Yes, I saw it, I am the one that upvoted it. However, I advise you to create a [MCVE], so you can get help faster.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Hum, ok my bad, I rewrote the question :-) ! If you copy/paste csv (as my_csv.csv) and html in the same folder, it will reproduce the error ! Thanks again.

Comment: Hi @GerardoFurtado ! I come back to you to know if you had time to see V4's version samples. Thanks in advance, and have a nice week-end !